# how to convert Result<Refmut<&[u8]>> to readable string

Tags: rust, solana

I'm quite new to rust and solana, and I want to unpack public key data to string.
I've googled for hours and tried few solutions like converting to base64 which was not good because it was not readable.
token slice is RefMut<&mut [u8]> after unwraping it

this is my code, trying to use the from_utf8 function however I'm getting an error (listed below)

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};
entrypoint!(process_handler);

fn process_handler(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    account_info: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts = &mut account_info.iter();
    let token_address = next_account_info(accounts)?;
    let user_address = next_account_info(accounts)?;
    let token_slice = token_address.try_borrow_mut_data().unwrap();
    msg!("token slice is {:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&token_slice));
    if !user_address.is_signer {
        msg!("Signer Error test");
        return Err(ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
    }
    msg!("this is user public key {}", user_address.key.to_string());
    return Err(ProgramError::IllegalOwner);
}
```

the error:

[image]

I've searched for hours and quite desperate, even if someone can give me a lead, that would be helpful.

Edit:
I'm attaching a picture of the token_slice data
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.7.13/src/solana_program/instruction.rs.html#236 says illegal account, can you put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Solana, a `Pubkey` is just 32 bytes of data, and the typical "string" representation is a base-58 encoding of those 32 bytes of data.  To resolve this, you can do:

```
let pubkey = Pubkey::new(&token_address.data.borrow()[..32]);
msg!("token slice is {}", pubkey);
```

Comment: There is no borrow_data function, and if I'm trying to use try_borrow_data, I get:
`cannot index into a value of type Result<Ref<'_, &mut [u8]>, ProgramError>`

Comment: Fixed the code snippet.

Comment: used 32..64 and worked, thanks.